# AMP-analytics: Passing useragent is truncated due to getNameArgs method

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

If I pass a string value containing `()` to the vars property in the `<amp-analytics>` component, the string is truncated due to the [regex](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/553492cf2c54e9c974ddea12b3c524a03b68de0b/extensions/amp-analytics/0.1/amp-analytics.js#L521) in the `getNameArgs_` string method.

Eg:

Passing the user agent from the request headers, renders as so:

```
"vars": {
     "userAgentHeader": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"
}
```

but will be passed in the analytics requests as `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4)`

This is because in [`encodeVars_`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/553492cf2c54e9c974ddea12b3c524a03b68de0b/extensions/amp-analytics/0.1/amp-analytics.js#L545) the raw value is passed to [`getNameArgs_`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/553492cf2c54e9c974ddea12b3c524a03b68de0b/extensions/amp-analytics/0.1/amp-analytics.js#L521) whose regex (`([^(]*)(\([^)]*\))?`) matches (`Mozilla/5.0` as first match and `(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4)` as second)

The data needs to match on AMP and on the main site - so even though I could use the Java URLEncoder (UTF-8), which would encode the brackets, the equivalent JS encodeURIComponent() *does not encode brackets* therefore I would need to convert back to . So the regex would still match on the equivalent encoding.

Using URLEncoder has this as the query param in the request (double encoding...):

`Mozilla%252F5.0%2B%2528Macintosh%253B%2BIntel%2BMac%2BOS%2BX%2B10_10_4%2529%2BAppleWebKit%252F537.36%2B%2528KHTML%252C%2Blike%2BGecko%2529%2BChrome%252F53.0.2785.116%2BSafari%252F537.36`

compared to this in a normal GA request:

`Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_10_4)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F53.0.2785.116%20Safari%2F537.36`

Even that exact string gets truncated to `Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_10_4)` if pasted directly into the object...

Maybe I am doing something completely wrong?

Comment: AMP Version 1477334765771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and was fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/6566) and will be released in version `1481838084444`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. Please file a bug report at: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new